# Question about Time Complexity analysis of Merge Sort

Tags: algorithm, sorting, recursive-datastructures

I'm a student starting to learn about Computer Science, specifically Data Structures and Algorithm.

Been struggling in understanding the Time Complexity of Merge Sort Algorithm, specifically deriving the worst, best and average complexity of it from it's recurrence relation.

I understand the how the algorithm works, but cant seem to explain the complexities from the equation from the number of key comparisons.

T(n) = 2T(n/2) + ɵ(n)

How do I prove the different time complexities from this relation?

Thank you!

I have tried simply solving the recurrence relation, by using method of backward substituition, and got the final complexity of O(nlogn), but I dont understand the idea of worst, best and average time complexity of this complexity.

Comment: The fun thing about merge sort is that for a given size input it always does the same sequence of comparisons. The initial order is irrelevant. Best case, worst case, and average case are all O(n log n).

Comment: @JimMischel it's not true that the number of comparisons is always the same -- in the merge step there's no more comparisons once one of the two arrays is used up. For a merge step, the best case is floor(n/2) comparisons, the worst case n-1 comparisons.  It's true that the complexities of the three cases are the same, but the worst case is almost twice as many comparisons as the best case overall.

Comment: @PaulHankin Thanks for the note. You're right: I over-stated my case.

Answer (score 0):

While it's often said (as a shortcut) "what is big-O time complexity of this algorithm?", it's important to understand that asymptotic analysis is not specific to algorithm complexity at all. It's just a tool for analysing behaviour of a single function for big numbers.

And asymptotic analysis has three often-used notations:

1. upper bound (big-O) - `f=O(g)` basically says that `f` doesn't grow faster than `g`, somewhat similar to `f<=g` if we ignore constants
2. lower bound (omega) - `f=Ω(g)` basically says that `f` doesn't grow slower than `g`, somewhat similar to `f>=g` if we ignore constants
3. tight bound (theta) - `f=ɵ(g)` means just that `g` is both the upper bound and the lower bound for `f`

If we are talking about analysis of an algorithm runtime for a single input, it's just a number. But if we are talking about its runtime for all arrays of length `N`, for some of them it will be faster, for some - lower. To analyse this variability people usually measure some statistical things, like `min (best)`, `max (worst)` and `average`. Every such property is a function of `N` and we can estimate any bound of any of these functions. For example, lower bound of the worst-case behaviour, etc.

So you don't derive best/worst/average asymptotic behaviour from a single formula. Instead you write some formula for each of them and explore their asymptotic behaviour.

A confusing factor here is that the standard implementation of the merge sort has identical formulas for best, worst and average runtimes. In general case they are different.

I've tried to represent this with a bad picture :)
[image]